# New installed Kali linux is not connecting to internet

Tags: networking, kali-linux, system-installation, dhcp

When I was installing Kali linux on my pc, I realized DHCP can't be configured so I skipped that part. After installation I used ifconfig and saw wlan0 was there but after opening a website I get this error that in which I have no internet connection.I had this problem with different kernel versions. any ideas with this problem?

Comment: You have given us no information other that it does not work. Kali is for advanced users only. Please find an alternative distro, learn Linux, then install Kali.

Comment: "_I realized DHCP can't be configured_" why not? A bit later, "_I skipped that part_" ... "_I have no internet connection_" well yes. If you don't get an IP address you're not going to get any Internet connectivity. Make/model of computer? Make/model of network card - is it wired or wireless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and this is how I solved it:

`sudo -i` for root permission

`rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf` to delete the resolv.conf

`echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`

And that's it

you can also check it using `nano /etc/resolv.conf`

**I hope it was useful for you**